# How to find row and column of an item in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
  A    B     C
0  True  True  False
1  True  True  True
2  False True True
```

I want to look for the instances of `False` and get its row and column.

Expected result: `[(0, 'C'), (2, 'A')]`. not exactly on this data structure format, but you get the drill.

I've tried doing this:

```
df[df.eq(False).any(1)]
```

What It does is filter out the rows where there's no `False` bool.

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series` and then filter indices by inverted values by `~` for match `False`s:

```
s = df.stack()
L = s.index[~s].tolist()
print (L)
[(0, 'C'), (2, 'A')]
```

Or get indices for `False`s in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and `zip` values for list of tuples:

```
i, c = np.where(~df)

L = list(zip(df.index[i], df.columns[c]))
print (L)
[(0, 'C'), (2, 'A')]
```